# Org-mode on the phone or on Evernote?

Tags: org-mode

I use Org mode for keeping track of everything; ideas, notes, to-do lists, code snippets, etc. You name it. One problem I have though, is that I can't easily pull up my Org-mode data on my phone, even if it is only for quickly checking my notes or searching within them.

To be clear, I store my org files within a Github repository, which is great, but this is still not amenable for smartphone browsing and searching.

Ideally what I am looking for is a way to synchronize org-mode notes with **Evernote**. Is this doable? If not, what are my alternatives for browsing org-mode files on my phone?

How can I easily sync, and later browse and search my org-mode files from my phone?

Comment: Have you looked at MobileOrg for org-mode on the phone?  http://mobileorg.ncogni.to/  No idea on Evernote.

Comment: It may behoove you to take a look at the org-mode toodledo library:  https://github.com/christopherjwhite/org-toodledo  I've been using it for the past year to host my business and personal calendars for all desktop and mobile devices.  I restored some of the default behavior by modifying the library so that I can use the same keywords in org-mode as with Toodledo -- i.e., active, next action, someday, reference, delegated, hold, postponed, canceled, waiting, planning.  And, I restored / configured the maximum priorities supported by Toodledo -- i.e., A, B, C, D and E.

Comment: MobileOrg is available for both iOS and Android: http://orgmode.org/manual/MobileOrg.html  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.matburt.mobileorg

Comment: Here is a related Emacs library to use Evernote -- however, I've never tried it out:  https://github.com/pymander/evernote-mode

Comment: For read-only access you could export your org file(s) as HTML and push them to a web server from which you can access them with your phone's browser.

Comment: Perhaps Eric Schulte's [`org-ehtml`](https://github.com/eschulte/org-ehtml) is of interest.  "`org-ehtml` allows for interactively viewing and editing Org-mode files through a web browser."

Answer (score 14):

I have been using [Orgzly](http://www.orgzly.com/) to view org files on Android.  It displays them nicely and you can do basic editing (setting todo states, schedules, deadlines and tags).  There is also some basic support `org-agenda` like searches.

Answer (score 4):

There is also [Geeknote](http://www.geeknote.me/), which at least gets Evernote to the command-line. You would still have to manually move things between org-mode and Geeknote though.

Update: Now there is [geeknote.el](https://github.com/avendael/emacs-geeknote). Haven't tried it yet but it looks nice.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to publish the org-mode files to HTML and browse the HTML versions from the mobile device.  I have my org-mode files stored in DropBox and set up as a project using [org-publish-project-alist](http://orgmode.org/guide/Publishing.html), and I use `M-x` `org-publish-all` to export them all to HTML files.  I customized the HTML slightly to improve the mobile view.  On my mobile device, I use the DropBox application to browse to the HTML version of the file.

This setup works fine.  I do have to remember to publish after making edits, and I plan eventually to write a hook that does this automatically.  The biggest drawback is that it doesn't allow editing on the mobile device.  Also, the mobile version is usable but a dedicated mobile application would be nicer.

The HTML customization I use for mobile display goes into `org-html-head-extra`:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1">
<style type="text/css">
  h2 { font-size: 1em; }
  h1 { font-size: 1.2em; }
  body { font-family: Calibri; }
</style>
```

Comment: Although this setup is working OK for getting access to my org-mode content on my mobile device, I am definitely still looking for a better solution.  I intend at some  point to test out the toodledo and trello synchronization libraries.